# Php and Javascript displaying the div after a click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a table with data from mysql database. There are, for example, 5 records. I want to do so when I click on a given record it will be displayed under some div class.
The problem is that when I click a given record only the first div class appears.

Code PHP:

```
foreach ($query as $value) {

  /** Table with records **/
  echo '<div class="table-flexbox-record">';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['id'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['photos'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['title'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['textads'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="buttonhv">P</a>';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  /** Box that needs to display **/
  echo '<div class="table-flexbox-information">';
      echo 'Sample text to must show';
  echo '</div>';

}
```

And there is.. when i click div class "table-flexbox-record" must show div class "table-flexbox-information" ( By default this div has in CSS: display: none; )

Code JavaScript: `

```
var recordClick = document.querySelectorAll('.table-flexbox-record');

for (var i = 0; i < recordClick.length; i++) {
    recordClick[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.querySelector('.table-flexbox-information').style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

How can i to do this?

Comment: Can you provide us with the actual HTML your PHP exports?

Comment: [html link code](https://paste.ofcode.org/47DQJME5BfmAeScapfHTyj)

Comment: Can you run the php script and give us the raw HTML without php?

Comment: [html without php](https://paste.ofcode.org/5FMSUeMPZSAHjw7Tikiu3G)

Comment: I do not know if I understood correctly but here is html and javascript only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now that I can see [your html](https://paste.ofcode.org/5FMSUeMPZSAHjw7Tikiu3G), the reason only the first "info" box shows its because `querySelector` just grabs the first match in the page.

```
document.querySelector('.table-flexbox-information') // always the first
```

#### You could instead do something like this:

```
this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
```

See it working in the snippet below...

```js
var deleteLink = document.querySelectorAll('.tabela-flexbox-rekord');

for (var i = 0; i < deleteLink.length; i++) {
  deleteLink[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      // make sure the next sibling is an "info block"
      if( this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('tabela-flexbox-informacje') )
          this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';

  });
}
```

```css
.tabela-flexbox-rekord {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.tabela-flexbox-rekord>* {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.tabela-flexbox-informacje {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container-tabela">


  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element-np tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      ID
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element-np tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys">
      Źródło
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element-np tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      Operacja
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element-np tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      Przynależność
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-rekord">
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-id tabela-rekord-wys">
      asdsa
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-zrodlo tabela-rekord-wys" style="text-align: left;">
      dasasdsad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-operacja tabela-rekord-wys">
      sadassad
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-rekord-element tabela-rekord-przyna tabela-rekord-wys">
      adssad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-flexbox-informacje">

    Some text to show

  </div>
  -->



</div>
```

## Update

Also, it would be smarter to make a `.show` class instead of changing the style with JS

```
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Then change code to this:

```
this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show)
```

Comment: Okey, querySelector grabs the first match.. i must use querySelectorAll.. but this does not work, does not even appear the first element.

Comment: oh, i see. It's work! I already see how you did it, I would never have bumped into it. Soon i will analyze it. Thank's soo much!

Comment: This works nicely and without querying the DOM, but keep in mind it only works as long as the next sibling of the item is indeed the target `div`. If you put anything between them, you'll need to change your code.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg – exactly. But considering he has control over the outputted html, it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin mentioned, `querySelector` only grabs the first result it finds over the *whole* page. However, as far as I understand, you want to search for the `.table-flexbox-information` *within* the item you're clicking, right?

Why not treat every one of these items within the iteration separately. Wrap them inside a `div` and do something like this:

```
foreach ($query as $value) {

  echo '<div class="table-container"> /* <--- Add this */
  /** Table with records **/
  echo '<div class="table-flexbox-record">';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['id'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['photos'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['title'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
      echo $value['textads'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="table-record-elem">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="buttonhv">P</a>';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  /** Box that needs to display **/
  echo '<div class="table-flexbox-information">';
      echo 'Sample text to must show';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>'; /* and add this */

}
```

Then, in your event listener:

```
var recordClick = document.querySelectorAll('.table-flexbox-record');

for (var i = 0; i < recordClick.length; i++) {
    recordClick[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        recordClick[i].parentNode.querySelector('.table-flexbox-information').style.display = 'block'; // Grab the parent of the item you clicked on, and perform the query selector for that container (which is the `.table-container` we just added).
    });
}
```

This limits the search of `querySelector` to just the relevant container.